# Magento 2 move tax section in to grand totals in cart page

Tags: magento2, cart, tax, shopping-cart, totals

I want to move the tax in between the order total incl tax and order total excl tax in the cartpage.

[image]

The Tax section is in the vendor/magento-tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/tax.html

And the order totals in vendor/magento-tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/grand-total.html

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You Can do this just Configuration. not require any custom code. please go to the below

Stores->Configuration->SALES->Sales->General->Checkout Totals Sort Order

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the admin:
Stores->Configuration->SALES->Sales->General->Checkout Totals Sort Order

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever find a solution for this? The answer of Jason is not working. You are not able to move the tax between the grand total ex VAT and grand total incl VAT, because there's only one grand total field.